Docker Desktop - Windows 11 - Unexpected WSL error

Docker Desktop - Windows 11 - Unexpected WSL error An unexpected error
occurred while executing a WSL command.

I'm having trouble with Docker Desktop on my Windows 11 system. I get an Unexpected WSL error when I try to run Docker.
I have attached a screenshot showing the error message after launching the Docker application for more context.

Also, the error message is as follows:
deploying WSL2 distributions
ensuring main distro is deployed: deploying "docker-desktop": importing WSL distro "WSL2 is not supported with your current machine configuration.\r\nPlease enable the \"Virtual Machine Platform\" optional component and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
Enable "Virtual Machine Platform" by running: wsl.exe --install --no-distribution
For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
Error code: Wsl/Service/RegisterDistro/CreateVm/HCS/HCS_E_HYPERV_NOT_INSTALLED
: exit status 0xffffffff
checking if isocache exists: CreateFile \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\isocache\: The network name cannot be found.


Did you follow the instructions in the error?  WSL2 (unlike WSL1) runs in a virtual machine, and as such you have to have installed the Windows Virtual Machine support.

Did it use to work before?

I blogged about how I got Docker to run here, do ensure that Virtualization is enabled in the BIOS https://nestenius.se/2024/09/24/running-docker-in-an-azure-windows-virtual-machine-not-so-fast/

Note: if you're trying to run Docker inside virtual machine, you need to enable nested virtualization.

pretty sure , it has to do with the windows feature virtual machine platform how to enable virtualisation
which also requires VT extension to be enabled. you can check it out

Error code: Wsl/Service/RegisterDistro/CreateVm/HCS/HCS_E_HYPERV_NOT_INSTALLED

this is what might be hinting at the same thing
and windows WSL FAQ's talk about it too

Yes. WSL 2 is available on all Desktop SKUs where WSL is available, including Windows 10 Home and Windows 11 Home. Specifically, WSL2 requires two features to be enabled: "Virtual Machine Platform" (a subset of Hyper-V)


I had same problem on Windows 10 even using latest versions Win10, WSL 2 and Docker Desktop with instruction
I found solution here. This worked for me:

Validate this by running (elevated powershell): bcdedit /enum | findstr -i hypervisorlaunchtype

If you see hypervisorlaunchtype Off, then the hypervisor is disabled. To enable it run in an elevated powershell: bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto

Reboot



wsl --set-default-version 2

this worked for me
